# How to access current location of any user using python

Tags: python, geolocation

Is there anyway that I can get the location of my device through python. Currently I am having to use selenium and open up a browser, use a location service website and setting the result of that to variables for lat/long.

But is there an easier way to do this?

UPDATE: I am using a 3G dongle on my RaspberryPi, so looking for a way to get the specific lat/long of it - I can successfully do this through web service, just wondering if there is a quicker way built into python for these requests?

Comment: See this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-time-zone-given-an-ip

Comment: I am not sure that is what I am looking for because that is a generic IP finding - I am wanting precise to my location, much like mobile geo-location.

Comment: When you say "the location of my device", are you talking about a mobile phone (or similar) or a desktop PC?

Comment: Maybe need to add clarity - I am using a 3G dongle with my Raspberry Pi, So want to be able to get the lat/long of it through a request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070169/is-it-possible-to-geo-locate-a-3g-usb-stick this question might help, but it looks (from a quick googling) like it's not going to be easy...

Comment: Here's some more information that might help - you'll need to get the GSM cell information from the device first tho: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329877/how-to-properly-triangulate-gsm-cell-towers-to-get-a-location

Answer (score 53):

or, as simple as this

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

Answer (score 22):

Others have mentioned a few services, but another one to consider is my own, https://ipinfo.io, which'll give you latitude, longitude and a bunch of other information:

**Usage for Bash:**

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "24.6.61.239",
  "hostname": "c-24-6-61-239.hsd1.ca.comcast.net",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3845,-122.0881",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, LLC",
  "postal": "94040"
}
```

If you only want the coordinate data you can get just that by requesting `/loc`:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/loc
37.3845,-122.0881
```

See https://ipinfo.io/developers for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Yours is more accurate than the accepted (albeit quite cool) answer, which sometimes returns the wrong continent…

Comment: @peppa ... the python addition made no sense. If that is an answer then ... post that part as an answer and refer to this answer here where I comment to your edit as curated at "From Review".

Answer (score 7):

Since `http://freegeoip.net/json` API endpoint is deprecated and will stop working on July 1st, 2018. So, they release new API `http://api.ipstack.com`.

So, you may try out this with new API:

```
import requests
import json

send_url = "http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
geo_req = requests.get(send_url)
geo_json = json.loads(geo_req.text)
latitude = geo_json['latitude']
longitude = geo_json['longitude']
city = geo_json['city']
```

In order to get your own `ACCESS_KEY`, you have to first create an account on `ipstack.com` which is free at https://ipstack.com/signup/free.

Along with `latitude`, `longitude` and `city`; you can also fetch `zip`, `continent_code`, `continent_name`, `country_code`, `country_name`, `region_code`, `region_name`.

**Limitation**: Free account only allow you 10,000 requests/month. If you requirement is more then you can upgrade you account.

For more information about this new API you can visit at [https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip](https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme)

Reference: @JishnuM answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python Geocoding Module that has GeoFreeIP

Example:
http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/

```
$ pip install geocoder
```

Using CLI

```
$ geocode '99.240.181.199' --provider freegeoip --pretty --json
```

Using Python

```
>>> import geocoder
>>> g = geocoder.freegeoip('99.240.181.199')
<[OK] Freegeoip - Geocode [Ottawa, Ontario Canada]>
>>> g.json
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) returns location data along with currency, time zone, and more for your current IP address or the given one (disclaimer, I run the service). There also exists an official Python client available on PyPI:

```
$ pip install ipregistry
```

```py
from ipregistry import IpregistryClient

client = IpregistryClient("tryout")  
ipInfo = client.lookup() 
print(ipInfo)
```

Unlike many other services, Ipregistry provides a lot of data including, carrier, company, in addition to city, latitude, longitude, currency, time zone, etc. all in a single and blazingly fast request.

Comment: Except that this gives very vague location results and now it shows my location in a different city which is a 6 hr drive. Downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying for months to get this and finally I came across a solution for windows users!
For me it got as close as the street name.
You need to install winrt(https://pypi.org/project/winrt/)
Here it is:

```
import winrt.windows.devices.geolocation as wdg, asyncio

async def getCoords():
        locator = wdg.Geolocator()
        pos = await locator.get_geoposition_async()
        return [pos.coordinate.latitude, pos.coordinate.longitude]
    
def getLoc():
    return ascyncio.run(getCoords())
```

Comment: One note is that you should use winapi instead of winrt. I think it is the more updated and reliable version and can be used in pretty much the same way.

Comment: nice it takes hardware location rather than by ip

Answer (score 1):

been playing around with this, so thanks to all for the useful answers in this thread (and SO in general!) thought I'd share my short program in case anyone wants to see it in combination with great circle calc

```
import geocoder

import requests
freegeoip = "http://freegeoip.net/json"
geo_r = requests.get(freegeoip)
geo_json = geo_r.json()

address=input('enter an address: ')
g= geocoder.google(address)
lat_ad=g.latlng[0]
lon_ad=g.latlng[1]

user_postition = [geo_json["latitude"], geo_json["longitude"]]
lat_ip=user_postition[0]
lon_ip=user_postition[1]

#Calculate the great circle distance between two points on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
# convert decimal degrees to radians 
lon_ad, lat_ad, lon_ip, lat_ip = map(radians, [lon_ad, lat_ad, lon_ip, lat_ip])

# haversine formula 
dlon = lon_ip - lon_ad 
dlat = lat_ip - lat_ad 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat_ad) * cos(lat_ip) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
km = 6367 * c
#end of calculation

#limit decimals
km = ('%.0f'%km)

print(address+' is about '+str(km)+' km away from you')
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-24906833&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) API

> This answer uses a 'test' API Key that is very limited and only meant for testing a few calls. [Signup](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-24906833-free-plan-cta&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) for your own Free API Key and get up to 1500 requests daily for development.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test').json()
r['country_name']
# United States
```

Answer (score 0):

@JishnuM answered the questions marvelously.

2 cents from me. You don't really need to import json library.

You can go as follows:

```
freegeoip = "http://freegeoip.net/json"
geo_r = requests.get(freegeoip)
geo_json = geo_r.json()

user_postition = [geo_json["latitude"], geo_json["longitude"]]

print(user_postition)
```

Answer (score 0):

The freegoip.net and the api.ipstack.com endpoints appear to use the location of the internet service provider (ISP), not the location of my device. I tried curl http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=YOUR_KEY, and what I got was

```
{"ip":"106.51.151.31","type":"ipv4","continent_code":"AS","continent_name":"Asia","country_code":"IN","country_name":"India","region_code":"KA","region_name":"Karnataka","city":"Bengaluru","zip":"560008","latitude":12.9833,"longitude":77.5833,"location":{"geoname_id":1277333,"capital":"New Delhi","languages":[{"code":"hi","name":"Hindi","native":"\u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940"},{"code":"en","name":"English","native":"English"}],"country_flag":"http:\/\/assets.ipstack.com\/flags\/in.svg","country_flag_emoji":"\ud83c\uddee\ud83c\uddf3","country_flag_emoji_unicode":"U+1F1EE U+1F1F3","calling_code":"91","is_eu":false}}
```

Checking the location lat, long on Google maps indicates that this is the location of the service provider, not the location of the server/device.

This solution is still usable, but probably only to a granularity of a city or country, based on how the ISP organises and locates its gateways.

Answer (score -2):

Location based on IP address gives only location for your server. To find location based on where your current location is, you would need to give the browser access to location. This can be done using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def getLocation():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    timeout = 20
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://mycurrentlocation.net/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    longitude = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="longitude"]')
    longitude = [x.text for x in longitude]
    longitude = str(longitude[0])
    latitude = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="latitude"]')
    latitude = [x.text for x in latitude]
    latitude = str(latitude[0])
    driver.quit()
    return (latitude,longitude)
print getLocation()
```

A tutorial on how to do it is [here](https://medium.com/@joeljogy07/how-i-understood-getting-accurate-geolocation-using-python-web-scraping-and-selenium-7967d721587a) or find the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/joeljogy/Getting-GeoLocation/)