# Get real location using python

Tags: python, location, ip

I tried to use api of this site(https://ipstack.com/) and wrote code bellow:

```py
r = requests.get(r'http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=key')
j = json.loads(r.text)
lat = j['latitude']
lon = j['longitude']
print(lat, lon)
```

This code gives me wrong location, it right defines city, but area is invalid.
How can i get my real location?

Comment: You can use `geocoder` as an alternative

Comment: @I don't think that geocoder can define geolocation by ip. Geocoder can define location by name string address

Comment: @Nikto It can define by IP. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906833/get-your-location-through-python#answer-43589918

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine here, though you might want to change the way you parse the response:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(r'http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=key')
j = r.json()
lat = j['latitude']
lon = j['longitude']
print(lat, lon)
print(j)
```

Comment: I don't know what exotic location you're in, but I think you have to ask the people from ipstack. It's not a code related issue.

Comment: @GijsWobben, do u know any another way to get location using python?

Comment: Google maps? https://medium.com/@n0tty/tracking-any-user-location-with-ip-address-using-google-api-9b58d8c62f89

Comment: @GijsWobben, i got another question.

signalToNoiseRatio: The current signal to noise ratio measured in dB.
signalStrength: The current signal strength measured in dBm.

Data:
Signal             : 100%  ', '         Radio type         : 802.11n',
Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11', '         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54'

How can i pull signalStrength and signalToNoiseRatio from my data?

Comment: Please post any new questions as new question in Stack Overflow.