# Python WinRT Geolocation RuntimeError

Tags: python, windows-runtime, windows-11

I am trying to read the geocoordinates from my windows device using the WinRT API with the solution suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65535202/6867283):

```
import winrt.windows.devices.geolocation as wdg, asyncio

async def getCoords():
    locator = wdg.Geolocator()
    pos = await locator.get_geoposition_async()
    print(pos)
    return [pos.coordinate.latitude, pos.coordinate.longitude]
    
asyncio.run(getCoords())
```

Unfortunately, I run into the following error...not much to go on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\locator.py", line 9, in <module>
    asyncio.run(getCoords())
  File "C:\path\to\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\path\to\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\path\to\locator.py", line 5, in getCoords
    pos = await locator.get_geoposition_async()
RuntimeError
```

I've also tried the exact solution in the [WinRT Documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/blob/master/src/package/pywinrt/projection/readme.md#:%7E:text=WinRT%20type%20methods%20that%20return%20an%20IAsync%2A%20interface,wdg%20async%20def%20get_current_latitude%20%28%29%3A%20locator%20%3D%20wdg.) without much luck.

This solution worked for me about a year ago. I have since switched from Windows 10 to Windows 11. Is it possible this is a Windows 11 issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

winrt is no longer maintained, you can use the community-supported [winsdk](https://pypi.org/project/winsdk/) fork.