# How to get my current Laptop Location using python?

Tags: python, gps, location

I have a laptop with GPS and cellular data. while on the road, how can I get my current location using python code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access current location of any user using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906833/how-to-access-current-location-of-any-user-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

There a few options , you will need to use some third party libraries like
[geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) [geocoder](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/)